# Facebook AdSet API "Your Budget is Too Low" error

Tags: json, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

**Problem**

I made a request to Facebook's Ad Set API attempting to create an ad set with the following JSON blob, and the error I received was "Your Budget Is Too Low. The minimum budget for this ad set is $32.04."

The ad set is set to use `auto_bid` and a valid `lifetime_target`. The ad set runs for 31 days, and with a $1 minimum daily budget, setting $64 for lifetime budget should've been sufficient.

**Attempted Solutions**

1. I tried to set a higher lifetime budget: from 64 to 1000 to 5000. 1000 did not work in this case, but 5000 did.

**JSON Blob Used**

```
    Array
    (
        [account_id] =>
        [adset_schedule] =>
        [bid_amount] =>
        [billing_event] => IMPRESSIONS
        [budget_remaining] =>
        [campaign_id] => 6054825216096
        [created_time] =>
        [creative_sequence] =>
        [daily_budget] =>
        [end_time] => 2016-11-08T07:59:59+0000
        [id] =>
        [is_autobid] => 1
        [lifetime_budget] => 64
        [lifetime_imps] =>
        [name] => Some-Test-Campaign
        [optimization_goal] => LINK_CLICKS
        [pacing_type] =>
        [recommendations] =>
        [rf_prediction_id] =>
        [start_time] => 2016-10-07T07:00:00+0000
        [updated_time] =>
        [targeting] => FacebookAds\Object\TargetingSpecs Object
            (
                [data:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [genders] =>
                        [age_min] =>
                        [age_max] =>
                        [geo_locations] => Array
                            (
                                [zips] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [key] => US:98004
                                            )

                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [key] => US:98005
                                            )

                                        [2] => Array
                                            (
                                                [key] => US:98006
                                            )

                                        [3] => Array
                                            (
                                                [key] => US:98007
                                            )

                                        [4] => Array
                                            (
                                                [key] => US:98008
                                            )

                                        [5] => Array
                                            (
                                                [key] => US:98009
                                            )

                                        [6] => Array
                                            (
                                                [key] => US:98011
                                            )

                                        [7] => Array
                                            (
                                                [key] => US:98014
                                            )

                                        [8] => Array
                                            (
                                                [key] => US:98015
                                            )

                                        [9] => Array
                                            (
                                                [key] => US:98019
                                            )

                                        [10] => Array
                                            (
                                                [key] => US:98021
                                            )
                                    )

                            )

                        [geo_markets] =>
                        [excluded_geo_locations] => Array
                            (
                                [countries] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                        [exclusions] =>
                        [user_adclusters] =>
                        [interests] =>
                        [user_os] =>
                        [user_device] =>
                        [wireless_carrier] =>
                        [page_types] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => desktopfeed
                                [1] => mobilefeed
                                [2] => mobileexternal
                                [3] => rightcolumn
                            )

                        [connections] =>
                        [excluded_connections] =>
                        [family_statuses] =>
                        [friends_of_connections] =>
                        [flexible_spec] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [interests] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [id] => 6003277229371
                                                    )

                                            )

                                        [behaviors] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [id] => 6017447625983
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                        [behaviors] =>
                        [relationship_statuses] =>
                        [interested_in] =>
                        [life_events] =>
                        [location_types] =>
                        [politics] =>
                        [markets] =>
                        [industries] =>
                        [income] =>
                        [net_worth] =>
                        [home_type] =>
                        [home_ownership] =>
                        [home_value] =>
                        [ethnic_affinity] =>
                        [generation] =>
                        [household_composition] =>
                        [moms] =>
                        [office_type] =>
                        [education_schools] =>
                        [education_statuses] =>
                        [college_years] =>
                        [education_majors] =>
                        [work_employers] =>
                        [work_positions] =>
                        [locales] =>
                        [zips] =>
                        [custom_audiences] =>
                        [custom_locations] =>
                        [excluded_custom_audiences] =>
                        [dynamic_audience_ids] =>
                        [product_audience_specs] =>
                        [excluded_product_audience_specs] =>
                    )

            )

        [promoted_object] =>
        [adlabels] =>
        [product_ad_behavior] =>
        [execution_options] =>
        [configured_status] =>
        [effective_status] =>
    )
```

I shortened the targeting for simplicity sake, but there's over 100 postal codes being targetd.

Answer (score 6):

The solution here is that `lifetime_budget` is denoted in cents, so $64 should be 6400.

Comment: life saving answer here, its not clear this is what they want.

Comment: daily budget is in cents too so if you want $10 you have to query the api with 1000.  6 hours of my life wasted on that lol.

Answer (score 5):

You may check if the budget you set is not less of required.

Perform this check at the endpoint:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/act_{ads_account_id}/minimum_budgets`

With headers:

`Authorization: Bearer {your token with 'ads_management' rights to this account}`

Returns:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "currency": "AED",
        "min_daily_budget_imp": 300,
        "min_daily_budget_video_views": 300,
        "min_daily_budget_high_freq": 750,
        "min_daily_budget_low_freq": 6000
    },
    {
        "currency": "ARS",
        "min_daily_budget_imp": 400,
        "min_daily_budget_video_views": 400,
        "min_daily_budget_high_freq": 1000,
        "min_daily_budget_low_freq": 8000
    }
]
}
```

PS. I see, that my response is 2 years late, but someone may find it useful.

Comment: Are there any ways to get the minimum lifetime budget value?